# XML Formatting in PHP

Tags: xml, formatting, break, double-quotes

I am trying to make an CML file that can be read with FusionCharts.

I have difficulties in formatting XML into this output :

```
<set label="Jan" value="420000" />
<set label="Feb" value="810000" />
```

What I have done

```
<?php
@date_default_timezone_set("GMT"); 
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '123')
or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db('tabel1') or die('Could not select database');

//get data from database
$sql="SELECT FROM";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

$xml = new XMLWriter();
$xml->openURI("php://output");
$xml->startDocument('1.0','UTF-8');
$xml->setIndent(5);
$xml->startElement('chart'); 
$xml->writeAttribute('caption', 'Monthly revenue for last year'); 
$xml->writeAttribute('subcaption', 'Harry&#39;s SuperMart'); 
$xml->writeAttribute('xaxisname', 'Month');
$xml->writeAttribute('yaxisname', 'Revenues (In USD)" theme="zune');

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

  $xml -> text('<set label=');
  $xml->writeRaw($row['date_']);
  $xml -> text(' values=');
  $xml->writeRaw($row['sum_']);
  $xml -> text(' />');  
}

$xml->endElement();
header('Content-type: text/xml');
$xml->flush();

?>
```

The code above will give output :

```
<set label=Jan value=420000 /><set label=Feb value=810000 />
```

I want to have "break" and double qoutes in each label and value parameter.

Thanks for your help